# Filter DataTable

Tags: c#, filter, datatable, datarow

I want to filter my DataTable based on certain filtering conditions.

Here's my code:

```
    parameters = objPatientBizProcessing.GetFilterParameters(campusSelection, statusSelection);
    filterOption3 = "pat_status = '" + parameters[1] + "'";

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dataRows = dt.Select(filterOption3, "id");
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in dataRows)
        {
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }
    }
```

I have a total of 10 records in my `dt`, and based on `filterOption3` I'm filtering the results to `dt1`.

**Error:**

> This row belongs to another Table

I'm not "allowed" to use a `DataView`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add rows to a `DataTable` that has been created using `dt.NewRow()` on that Table. You need to use `dt.ImportRow(row)`.

Can you not use the `dataRows` collection from the select directly instead?

Comment: you mean Add the datarow collection to another table, and then filter?

Comment: No, I'm just wondering why you need to insert the filtered rows into another DataTable.

Comment: I don't need to actually, something I'm told to do :\

Comment: Just use ImportRow instead of Add than.